# Property of free modules.

Tags: modules

Let $R$ be a PID. I want to show that if $P$ is a finitely generated left $R$-module and $P$ is isomorphic to $R^n$ and $R^m$ (as $R$-modules) for $n,m$ in the natural numbers, then $n=m$. 
I was wondering if the following proof is enough:
Assume $m<n$. Let $f: R^m \to R^n$ be isomorphic. Then the image of the basis for $R^m$ generates $R^n$. But then $m$ elements generate $R^n$, showing that $m=n$.

I'm not that good at working with modules, so my question is, if this proof is valid?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid not. The *invariant basis number*  or *IBN* property is not satisfied by all rings.

It is true for the so-called *stably free* rings, for which, given two $n\times n$ matrices, $AB=I_n\Rightarrow BA=I_n$.

Among stably free rings are commutative rings, noetherian rings, artinian rings and semi-local rings.

An example of a ring that does not satisfy IBN is $R=\mathbf{CFM}_\mathbf{N}(A)$, the set of infinite matrices, indexed by $\mathbf N\times\mathbf N$ with coefficients in a ring $A$ and only a finite number of non-zero coefficients  in each column.

One shows the map:
$$\begin{aligned}
R&\longrightarrow R\times R\\
X&\longmapsto (O,E)
\end{aligned}\quad \text{where}\quad \begin{array}{|l}O=\text{odd columns of }X,\\E=\text{even columns of }X\end{array}$$
is such an  isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In my case, $R$ is a PID. Does PID's have this IBN property?

Comment: If you mean a *commutative* PID, yes, like all commutative ring. If you mean a left (or right) principal ideal ring, it is left (or right) noetherian, so yes in that case too.

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to be helpful.