# Isomorphic distinct powers of the same ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

It is possible to have a ring $A$,  with identity,  such that $A^m\cong A^n$ as left $A$-modules and with $m\neq n$?

I have that for commutative rings this is not possible, but I have no idea of the proof.

Comment: These rings for which this not possible are known as *IBN rings* (Invariant Basis Number rings) and include (subrings of) skewfields. See for instance the  answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297934/property-of-free-modules/1297994#1297994). There an example of a ring that does not have this property.

Answer (score 1):

Tensor each side with $A/m$, where $m \in Spec(A).$ By noting that $A/m \otimes A^n \simeq A^n/mA^n $ is a $n$-dimensional vector space over $A/m$, compare the dimensions on both sides.